# Backpropagation for a simple neural network giving unusual results

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

A few days ago I tried to put in practice what I learned this year in an AI lecture, concerning neural networks. I tried to make a simple one, with only 2 neurons, that would replicate its input signal. Here's a little drawing of the network, with my calculations: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKinR.jpg (sorry for the comments in French, they're not really important)

The weird thing is that it does converge, but for a simple binary input signal, when the signal is 0, the network effectively sends ~0, but when it's 1, it sends ~0.5, and I don't understand why. Plus, I have to set the learning rate quite high (~100) to get it working, again I don't know why.

Here's the java code I used to test the network:

```
public class Main
{
    final static double R = 100;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double w1 = Math.random(), w2 = Math.random();

    for (int iter = 1; iter <= 100; iter++)
    {
        int x;

        if (Math.random() >= 0.5)
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            x = 0;
        }

        double p1 = x * w1;
        double y = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-p1));

        double p2 = y * w2;
        double z = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-p2));

        double P = -0.5 * Math.pow(x - z, 2);

        double dP1 = (x - z) * z * (1 - z) * w2 * y * (1 - y) * x;
        double dP2 = (x - z) * z * (1 - z) * y;

        w1 += R * dP1;
        w2 += R * dP2;

        System.out.println("x = " + x + ", z = " + z + ", P = " + P);
    }
}

}
```

Do you have any idea where the problem could come from?

Thanks.

LeChocdesGitans

Edit:

I finally managed to get it working (I followed your advice for the network configuration). I suppose there was also an implementation mistake, because it didn't work directly after I changed the layout of the network, but I started it all over again, and now I can do pretty interesting stuff, like character recognition, which works quite well, compare to how basic my application is.

Thanks again for you advice!

Comment: I am curious, why did you choose to use two layers with one neuron each ?

Comment: Well, since I don't have a lot of experience in machine learning, I just used a setup that I saw in one of the MIT's videos about neural networks. What do you think is best?

Comment: A setup of one layer with two perceptrons is more functional and "realistic" as a toy example.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it when I have time and see what difference it makes. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: It is not directly related to your problem (which unfortunately I cannot test at the moment) but it is always better to try an simulate realistic examples an the one you are using is not. It is also very useful to begin with a toy example you can validate on paper and then expand. For example, I would suggest implementing the classic x-or classification task: http://www.mind.ilstu.edu/curriculum/artificial_neural_net/xor_problem_and_solution.php

Comment: Alright, I'll try this one first, then. Thanks! By the way, why do you think my setup is not realistic (just a simple question, since I have no idea how to choose the best setup)?

Comment: Please provide an example that compiles and runs, per StackOverflow posting guidelines.  This code has an extra closing brace, as well as failing to compile at line 1.

Answer (score 1):

As **rpd** said, your main problem is that you're training two successive layers.  Mathematically, this means that all of the correction applied to node 1 has to be filtered through node 2.  Yes, you can apply the chain rule, Bayes' theorem, or other equivalent filtering, but this always runs the risk of implementation error.

From the effects you describe, you almost certainly have an error in your implementation.  The largest clue to this is that you had to raise your learning rate above any reasonable value to get even marginally acceptable results.  Remember, this is the scaling factor to recognize taking small steps.  A value of 100 means that you're taking your best current estimate of the correct adjustment, and then going 100 times as far.  If the rest of your algorithm is correct, a learning rate more than 1.0 is an intentional attempt to oscillate wildly without ever converging.

If you've tracked your intermediate values, please post the sequence of updates; if not, then you should use that debugging step.

However, you should first put your hidden neurons in parallel, not in series.  For one thing, the convolution of functions is simply wasteful of steps.  For another, the weights should be updated through the same process (in parallel).  The result should converge on distinct weights that are easily normalized to 1.0 (say, through a SoftMax operation).  One-layer back-propagation is a low-order computation: debug the process with a simple linear process (Euler's method) before you try for the faster convergence with the cubic (and worse) error functions you set up.

---

I worked with your notes and algorithm a little, and got a couple of observations.

- You dropped a negative sign in the first line of your notes: if P(x, z) = -1/2 (x-z)^2, then the derivative is -(x-z), or z-x.  Making this change in the algorithm helps the convergence somewhat.
- The convolution of neurons in series is generally flawed; this reduces trivially to a model with a single hidden neuron.